ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' error when trying to run dbt
When trying to run the following command:
dbt run
I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/homebrew/bin/dbt", line 5, in <module>     from dbt.cli.main import cli   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>     from .main import cli as dbt_cli  # noqa     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/cli/main.py", line 14, in <module>     from dbt.cli import requires, params as p   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/cli/requires.py", line 1, in <module>     import dbt.tracking   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/tracking.py", line 15, in <module>     from dbt import version as dbt_version   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/version.py", line 11, in <module>     import dbt.semver   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/semver.py", line 6, in <module>     import dbt.utils   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/utils.py", line 20, in <module>     from dbt.events.types import RetryExternalCall, RecordRetryException   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/events/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>     from .adapter_endpoint import AdapterLogger  # noqa: F401     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/events/adapter_endpoint.py", line 3, in <module>     from dbt.events.functions import fire_event, EVENT_MANAGER   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/events/functions.py", line 2, in <module>     from dbt.events.base_types import BaseEvent, EventLevel, EventMsg   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/events/base_types.py", line 4, in <module>     from dbt.events import types_pb2   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/events/types_pb2.py", line 5, in <module>     from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'      

I have tried to uninstall dbt, dbt-postgres, google and reinstalling the modules.  I had this dbt project running successfully before, but after creating a new environment I can't get it to run. Current dbt and google modules from pip list:
db-dtypes                     1.2.0
dbt                           1.0.0.38.12
dbt-adapters                  1.1.1
dbt-common                    1.0.4
dbt-core                      1.8.0
dbt-extractor                 0.5.1
dbt-postgres                  1.8.2
dbt-semantic-interfaces       0.5.1
google                        3.0.0
google-api-core               2.19.0
google-auth                   2.29.0
google-cloud-bigquery         3.23.1
google-cloud-core             2.4.1
google-cloud-dataproc         5.9.3
google-cloud-storage          2.16.0
google-crc32c                 1.5.0
google-resumable-media        2.7.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.63.0


What is the run command?

Sorry meant to be dbt run @JohnGordon

I think you are missing the Protobuf module required for serializing the structured data by dbt. Try doing pip install protobuf. Should solve the issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
